# How can you write a conditional based on the definedness of multiple variables?

Tags: null, conditional-statements, undefined, raku

Every now and then I find myself needing to write conditionals with two or three branches: at minimum, one for when all of two or more variables are defined and one for when any or none of those are defined. Sometimes that last branch needs to be two separate branches. What are some short and sweet ways of writing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`with`, `without`, and `orwith` are conditionals that work similarly to `if`, `unless`, and `elsif`, except they check for the definedness of their argument instead of their truthiness. Junctions get threaded when used in combination with these, so a conditional like that can be written like this:

```
my Str $foo = '' if 2.rand.floor;
my Str $bar = '' if 2.rand.floor;
with $foo & $bar {
    say 'yes';
} orwith $foo | $bar {
    say 'maybe';
} else {
    say 'no';
}
```

Or for an arbitrary number of variables:

```
my Str @strings = do 2.rand.floor ?? '' !! Nil for ^3;
with all @strings {
    say 'yes';
} orwith any @strings {
    say 'maybe';
} else {
    say 'no';
}
```

Comment: hi @kaiepi - please can you explain what is the :_ for in the my Str:_ ... statements??

Comment: hi @kaiepi - I am worried that the reputation of perl as line noise is continuing with perl6 - so I propose to use the default ‘Str’ which is (i) something that works with less noise and (ii) someone thought about and defined, unless I misunderstand and there is some value in the ‘:_’

Comment: In my own code, I prefer to be explicit with type smileys, but I can see why people don't like `:_`. I'll edit it out.

Answer (score 6):

`with` et al are great, and I might write a chained `with` statement, especially if the matching of particular variable combinations was ad hoc or I thought could become so given expected evolution of the code.

But given your literal question, and the scenario you have in your answer, I'd much more likely go with `given`/`when` instead:

```
my ($foo, $bar, $baz) = (Mu, 42).pick xx Inf;

given $foo, $bar, $baz {
  when .all.defined { say 'yes'   }
  when .any.defined { say 'maybe' }
  default           { say 'no'    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of using`when` / `default` here, if you really mean `if` / `elsif` / `else` ?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen ➊ I prefer how it reads. One keyword rather than three (`default` is optional outside exception handlers). ➋ `when`'s smart without `$_ ~~`. That doesn't matter until it does, but `when` it does, it does. ➌ `when` supports `proceed` / `succeed` (statement modifier `when` too). Again, this doesn't matter until it does, but `if` doesn't, period. ➍ Each time I refactored a *set topic* / `if` / `elsif` / `else` chain to accommodate ➋ or ➌ I thought about ➊ and the famous yagni's less well known annoying identical twin (you *are* gonna need it). ➎ I use `if` if speed matters...

Answer (score 5):

You could create a combined value and use a signature as a `when` conditional.

( `:(…)` is the syntax for a Signature literal. )

```raku
given ($foo,$bar,$baz) {
   when :( Any:D, Any:D, Any:D ) { 'all defined' }
   when :( Any:D, Any:D, Any:U ) { '$baz undefined' }
   when :( Any:D, Any:_, Any:D ) { '$bar not checked' }

   default { … }
}
```

You could create lexical constants to make it shorter.

```raku
my constant D = Any:D; # defined
my constant U = Any:U; # undefined
my constant _ = Any:_; # either

given ($foo,$bar,$baz) {
   when :(D,D,D) { 'all defined' }
   when :(D,D,U) { '$baz undefined' }
   when :(D,_,D) { '$bar not checked' }

   default { … }
}
```

Or if you want it to be more visual:

```raku
my constant term:<▣> = Any:D; # defined
my constant term:<□> = Any:U; # undefined
my constant term:<▨> = Any:_; # either

given ($foo,$bar,$baz) {
   when :(▣,▣,▣) { 'all defined' }
   when :(▣,▣,□) { '$baz undefined' }
   when :(▣,▨,▣) { '$bar not checked' }

   default { … }
}
```

You could create a subroutine that gives the Signature to use instead.

```raku
## something like this should work
## but something is weird with the returns constraint
#sub prefix:<d> ( $_ ) {
#  my constant %lookup = (
#    '▣' => Parameter.new( type => Any:D ),
#    '□' => Parameter.new( type => Any:U ),
#    '▨' => Parameter.new( type => Any:_ ),
#  );
#  Signature.new: params => %lookup{.comb}
#}

sub prefix:<d> ( $_ ) {
  my constant %lookup = (
    '▣' => 'Any:D',
    '□' => 'Any:U',
    '▨' => 'Any:_',
  );
  use MONKEY-SEE-NO-EVAL;
  EVAL ":(%lookup{.comb}.join(","))"
}

given ($foo,$bar,$baz) {
   when d'▣▣▣' { 'all defined' }
   when d'▣▣□' { '$baz undefined' }
   when d'▣▨▣' { '$bar not checked' }

   default { … }
}
```